# Are there cumulative driver additions from repeated syspreps on different PCs?

Tags: windows, drivers, sysprep

e.g. I have a master PC, install drivers and sysprep and take image.
On PC 2 I installed that image, update any drivers, sysprep and take image.
Move to PC 3, install the image, update drivers, sysprep and take image.

Now will this final image contain drivers for all 3 PC types?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will work, but it is a bad idea. Sysprep maintains a count of how many times it's been run. If you do this, you'll max out that count and make a lot of work for yourself.

Install all of your drivers on the first machine, then sysprep it.

If you're using WDS, you can push drivers with the image. Also, you can use dism to add drivers to an offline image before you push it down.

**EDIT**

Since you're running XP, there is a Microsoft approved way of adding drivers to the image. This might work out much better for you. Check out this KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314479

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't think there is a limit if you are on Volume Licence?

Comment: Even with a volume license there is a 3 sysprep limit. VL still needs activation and the limit was imposed to prevent people from trying to circumvent activation with sysprep.

Comment: I'm doing XP SP3 sysprep, if that makes a difference?

Comment: That does make a difference. VL versions of XP do not require activation. There is no sysprep limit. There is a way to have sysprep install drivers for you though.

Comment: Resetting Windows Activation
 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766514(WS.10).aspx. "If you anticipate running Sysprep multiple times on a single computer, you must use the SkipRearm setting"

Answer (score 0):

For **Win XP** If you have Volume Licence AND VL media, you can do it as many times as you want!  See the MS link :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299840